# How can I include a link to XSLT file with Python ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, elementtree

I'm trying hard to include my XSLT header in my XML with ElementTree, and I can´t find any information on how to do it.

Here's my Python code:

```
tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml') #get all tags from this XML document

root = tree.getroot()  #get all elements from each tag

root[0][0].text = "ole"

root[0][1].text = "ole"

tree.write('test_file.xml', encoding='utf-8', method="xml") #write XML file
```

The only problem is to include this header:

`<\? xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xsl"  \?>`

Comment: This is called a processing instruction. I am not familiar with ElementTree, but this seems like it does what you want: http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree.ProcessingInstruction-function

Comment: thanks wasmachien! i will check it and say something after

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) does not support XSLT (for instance, you can read about [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) that `method` is either *xml*, *text* or *html*).

Luckily though, you can easily do that if you rely on [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/index.html) which adds supports to [`XSLT`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer!!!

You need to use lxml instead and this is the new code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET 

parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False) #strip = false to prevent cdata to be removed/ stripped 
tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml', parser) 
root = tree.getroot()  #get all elements from each tag

tag1 = root.find('TAG1')
tag1.find('TAG2').text = 'text change here'

tree.write('test_file.xml', encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```

Your XML template (myfile.xml) is like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your_file.xsl" ?>
<FirstTAG>              
        <TAG1>      
             <TAG2>your text</TAG2>
        </TAG1>
</FirstTAG>
```

And the new one will be like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your_file.xsl" ?>
<FirstTAG>              
        <TAG1>      
             <TAG2>text change here</TAG2>
        </TAG1>
</FirstTAG>
```